# Grab select options with javascript

Tags: javascript, select

I have two boxes that switch data between each other. By default, the last box are empty and only receives items added by the user, clicking on ">" button.

Now, I need a action to grab these items in a simple alert via JS.

When the user add items to the box on right and click on "grab all" button, needs to show an alert with the selected (pushed) items.

Here's the HTML:

```
<form method="get" style="width:400px">             
   <select id="SelectLeft" multiple="multiple" style="float:left">
        <option value="1">Wood</option>
        <option value="2">Steel</option>
        <option value="3">Iron</option>
        <option value="4">Carbon Fiber</option>
   </select>


<div class="btns">
  <input id="filter_right" type="button" value=" > " />
  <input id="filter_left" type="button" value=" < " />
</div>
  <select id="SelectRight" multiple="multiple" style="float:right">

  </select>

    <input type="submit" value="grab all" />
 </form>
```

Here is the JS fiddle of this issue: http://jsfiddle.net/pamDe/4/

What can I do to make this action on that button? Any help or reference will be strongly grateful.

Thanks in advice!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a working example, to show you what has been selected

http://jsfiddle.net/3twAN/

```
$("#graball").live('click',function(event) {
            event.preventDefault();
            var foo = "";

            $('#SelectRight :selected').each(function(i, selected){
              foo = foo + $(selected).text() + " ";
            });

            alert(foo);
        });
```